# Assign multiple values per key in a Java Map

Tags: java, java-8

Creating a standard `Map` in Java is easy.

```java
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, "Name 1");
map.put(2, "Name 2");
```

Now I need to "extend" this standard map approach, so that each key can represent multiple values, e.g. like this:

```java
Map<Integer, String, String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, "Name 1", "Address 1", "ZIP Code 1");
map.put(2, "Name 2", "Address 2", "ZIP Code 2");
```

Is there any "standard" implementation or library which provides such a feature? I'm aware of e.g. Apache Commons `MultiValuedMap` (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html) but this doesn't seem to fit the above use case.

Comment: Have you considered storing lists? Or in your case, bundling the strings into an object?

Comment: Name, address and zip code? This sounds like you should create a `Person` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better option is likely to make an object to contain your info:

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String zip;

    ...
}
```

You can use the class as your value type:

```
Map<Integer, Person> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, new Person("Name 1", "Address 1", "ZIP Code 1"));
map.put(2, new Person("Name 2", "Address 2", "ZIP Code 2"));
```

As of java 16, you can use a [record class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/records.html) to make the container:

```
record Person(String name, String address, String zip) {}
```

Comment: @user16320675 It's hard to imagine you actually want to store the age of a person instead of just their birthdate.

Answer (score 3):

Your value can be a List of Strings, like this:

```java
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

The more readable way is to initialize a value list and then put it to the map as a value:

```java
ArrayList<String> value1 = new ArrayList<String>();
value1.add("Name 1");
value1.add("Address 1");
value1.add("ZIP Code 1");

ArrayList<String> value2 = new ArrayList<String>();
value1.add("Name 2");
value1.add("Address 2");
value1.add("ZIP Code 2");

Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, value1);
map.put(2, value2);
```

But you can initialize it inline too

```java
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1,  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Name 1", "Address 1", "ZIP Code 1")));
map.put(2,  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Name 2", "Address 2", "ZIP Code 2")));
```

Comment: This will certainly work, but creating a Person class as suggested above, and using it as the value might be a better approach in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap
already does this in a generic fashion.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should create a nested DTO class that contains those attributes.